# How to check session in a central place

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a webforms application. Almost all pages in my website are protected by login. Currently I am checking session exists or not in Page_Load event of all forms. Is there a way that I can do it in just one place which applies to all pages.

Comment: TheGeek has the answer to your question; but are you checking to see if the user is logged in via a session variable?  If you are, there are much better built in methods. (e.g. FormsAuthentication)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that inherits from Web.UI.Page.  In that class, create an event for Page_Load and put your code that checks for the session.  Then on all of the pages you want to be protected by login, have them inherit the class you create.

Comment: you mean I should create page_load event in sessionCheck  class I created? and not in actual page which inherits from sessionCheck class?

Comment: You can have that event in both.  But in the class you create that inherits from Page, in the Page_Load event there do your session checking for you login.

Comment: But If I add page_load event in both then Base class's page_load event doesn't fire.

Comment: did you declare the class abstract?

Comment: protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
       // ... add custom logic here ...
       
       // Be sure to call the base class's OnLoad method!
       base.OnLoad(e);
    }

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to define an abstract page (say SessionedPageBase) and make all your other pages inherit from it.

You can either call the base Page_Load the first thing in the individual pages Page_Load, or better - create an event (as suggested in the other answers).

Comment: how to create the event in class? Can you show me any example?

Comment: If I add page_load event in both then Base class's page_load event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment from @rkw, I think you might be better off using Forms Authentication for this instead of your own custom mechanism.

If you use Forms authentication, then you can specify which pages are protected using entries in web.config.

For a good introduction to Forms authentication, see https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150650/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110701-1.shtml